# Python subprocess returning output as stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've been working on a Python script to interact with ffmpeg; however, I've noticed that even though everything runs fine, stdout is empty and stderr returns what I should expect from stdout. How do I fix it so that the output will be returned by stdout?

Here's the simplest example that reproduces the phenomenon:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python', '-V'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if out:
    print("Output. ", out.decode())
else:
    print("Error. ", err.decode())
```

Here's the output:

```
Error.  Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

I should note that I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: What is your question here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the `stderr` of your process to its `stdout`by doing so:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-V"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Then you can retrieve the output produced by the process like so:

```
out = p.stdout.read()
```

This will return the content of the stdout after your process has terminated.